# Modificar propiedad de Objeto Json con su nombre como argumento de una funcion

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-2015

Quiero crear una función que modifique el valor de una propiedad mediante su nombre que recibe como argumento de tipo string

```js
let Personas = [
  {nombre: 'Juan',
   apellido: 'Perez'},
  {nombre: 'Maria',
   apellido: 'Gonzales'},
  {nombre: 'Mario',
   apellido: 'Ramirez'},
  {nombre: 'Elba',
   apellido: 'Ginon'}
]

function modPersona(ptomod,propiedad,valor){
  Personas.map((persona) => {
    if(persona === ptomod){
      // Aqui quiero modificar una propiedad del objeto persona da la cual obtengo el nombre mediante el argunmento propiedad
      /* Algo asi
        persona.propiedad = valor
      */
    }
  })
}

let personaamodificar = Personas[0]

modPersona(personaamodificar,'nombre','Alberto')

Personas.map((persona) => {
  console.log(persona.nombre + ' ' + persona.apellido)
})
```

Comment: Para modificar el valor de una propiedad solo sería : `persona[propiedad]=valor;` donde `propiedad` y `valor` son pasados por parámetro a la función.

Comment: Gracias, siempre utilizo el punto para acceder a las propiedades de json y olvide que era posible hacerlo esta manera